# Eclipse problem does not start on 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse

Just yesterday eclipse was working fine. But today it get's stuck on the small window,after eclipse launch screen. Don't know what exactly is the problem.
Due to low reputation i'am unable to post the screenshot.

Comment: Whats thr error log saying ir even the error ita throwing

Comment: You can get the error either by running eclipse directly from a terminal or from the [log](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F)

Comment: @OluDoug No error message , nothing. Only a small blank window.

Comment: @AJefferiss - Yes , I once run it from terminal.

Comment: @AkashChavan you need to post the contents of the log, link in my previous comment, before we can help. If you get the error in a terminal, take a screenshot and upload it to a free site like [imgur](http://imgur.com/) then someone can embed it into your post for you. Or just copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Or pipe the output to a file like so: `/path/to/eclipse |& tee my-eclipse-log.txt`